# Set custom cookie in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Is there a way to set a custom cookie on retrofit requests?

Either by using the `RequestInterceptor` or any other means?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Through the `retrofit.RequestInterceptor`:

```
@Override
public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {    
     request.addHeader("Cookie", "cookiename=cookievalue");
}
```

You can set a custom `RequestInterceptor` as follows:

```
String cookieKey = ...
String cookieValue = ...

RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
      @Override
      public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
        // assuming `cookieKey` and `cookieValue` are not null 
        request.addHeader("Cookie", cookieKey + "=" + cookieValue);
      }
    })
    .setServer("http://...")
    .build();

YourService service = adapter.create(YourService.class);
```

And to read any cookies set by the server, attach a custom cookie manager like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
CustomCookieManager manager = new CustomCookieManager();
client.setCookieHandler(manager);

RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setClient(new OkClient(client))
    ...
    .build();
```

where `CustomCookieManager` could look like this:

```
public class CustomCookieManager extends CookieManager {

  // The cookie key we're interested in.    
  private final String SESSION_KEY = "session-key";

  /**
   * Creates a new instance of this cookie manager accepting all cookies.
   */
  public CustomCookieManager() {
    super.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
  }

  @Override
  public void put(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders) throws IOException {

    super.put(uri, responseHeaders);

    if (responseHeaders == null || responseHeaders.get(Constants.SET_COOKIE_KEY) == null) {
      // No cookies in this response, simply return from this method.
      return;
    }

    // Yes, we've found cookies, inspect them for the key we're looking for.
    for (String possibleSessionCookieValues : responseHeaders.get(Constants.SET_COOKIE_KEY)) {

      if (possibleSessionCookieValues != null) {

        for (String possibleSessionCookie : possibleSessionCookieValues.split(";")) {

          if (possibleSessionCookie.startsWith(SESSION_KEY) && possibleSessionCookie.contains("=")) {

            // We can safely get the index 1 of the array: we know it contains
            // a '=' meaning it has at least 2 values after splitting.
            String session = possibleSessionCookie.split("=")[1];

            // store `session` somewhere

            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where did you add this code exactly and did you have to do anything else? Also, what goes in cookiename=cookievalue?

Comment: @Eric: How did you obtain the cookievalue from the response?

Comment: I want to know the same thing

Comment: @David What is `Constants.SET_COOKIE_KEY`?

Comment: @David How do you add the cookie to `sharedPreferences` in the `CookieManager`?

Comment: This answer is old as the new version of Retrofit does not use a RestAdapter class anymore. Any idea how to set cookies on Retrofit 2?

Answer (score 3):

This is how it's done for **retrofit2**

*Gradle:*

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
```

*The code:*

```
static final class CookieInterceptor implements Interceptor {
            private volatile String cookie;

            public void setSessionCookie(String cookie) {
                this.cookie = cookie;
            }

            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request();
                if (this.cookie != null) {
                    request = request.newBuilder()
                            .header("Cookie", this.cookie)
                            .build();
                }
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
}


class Creator {

    public static MyApi newApi() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
                .create();

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new CookieInterceptor())
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(MyApi.URL)
                .callFactory(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(MyApi.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to set a cookie is this way:

```
@Headers("Cookie: cookiename=cookievalue")
@GET("widget/list")
Call<List<Widget>> widgetList();
```

And here is a dynamic way:

```
@GET("user")
Call<User> getUser(@Header("Cookie") String cookie)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've only just started with RetroFit, but the way it handles cookies does not seem to be on par with the rest of the library. I wound up doing something like this:

```
// Set up system-wide CookieHandler to capture all cookies sent from server.
final CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

// Set up interceptor to include cookie value in the header.
RequestInterceptor interceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
  @Override
  public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
    for (HttpCookie cookie : cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()) {
      // Set up expiration in format desired by cookies
      // (arbitrarily one hour from now).
      Date expiration = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
      String expires = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz")
          .format(expiration);

      String cookieValue = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + "; " +
          "path=" + cookie.getPath() + "; " +
          "domain=" + cookie.getDomain() + ";" +
          "expires=" + expires;

      request.addHeader("Cookie", cookieValue);
    }
  }
};

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
    .setRequestInterceptor(interceptor) // Set the interceptor
    .build();

GitHubService service = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);
```

Comment: I definitely agree with your statement that the cookie handling is sub-par.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a simple and clean way to send and receive cookies in `OkHttp` and `Retrofit` requests,  I suggest using the [`CookieJar`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-cookie-jar/) interface.

Initially, create a class and implement the `CookieJar` interface and its functions. In this class, you can receive and send cookies.

```
import okhttp3.Cookie
import okhttp3.CookieJar
import okhttp3.HttpUrl

class MyCookieJar : CookieJar {

    val cookieStorage = CookieDataStore()

    override fun saveFromResponse(url: HttpUrl, cookies: List<Cookie>) {
        // Receive cookies from API requests here:
        cookieStorage.storeCookies(cookies)
    }

    override fun loadForRequest(url: HttpUrl): List<Cookie> {
        // Set cookies to your API requests here:
        return cookieStorage.getCookies()
    }

}
```

Subsequently, introduce `MyCookieJar` to your `OkHttpClient`:

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cookieJar(MyCookieJar())
        .build()
```