# android: how to send multiple cookie values in retrofit

Tags: android, cookies, retrofit2

Hi I am using retrofit below code where I am sending only one cookie value

```
 @POST("someUrl")
 Call<Model> apiCall(@Header("Cookie") String sid, @Body Model model);
```

But I need to send multiple cookie value in request
for example

```
Cookie: user_id=Administrator; system_user=yes; full_name=Administrator; sid=012345
```

How do I send this type of cookie in request. please help me out. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Make custom `Header Interceptor`

Comment: can you please elaborate.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530307/set-custom-cookie-in-retrofit)

Comment: Thanks @MD It is working.